# Convert Java Date as String into JsDate?

Tags: java, json, gwt

I have a Java/Groovy Date which an converted into a String.

```
Date myDate = new Date();
dateForClient = myDate.toString();
```

dateForClient is sent to the client via JSON. So the client receives a JSONString ob dateForClient.

I can receive the String as:

```
String dateOnClient = jsonMessage.get("dateForClient").isString().stringValue();
```

1. How can I convert this dateOnClient into a com.google.gwt.core.client.JsDate?
2. Do I have to call the toString() method on the server side before sending the Date via JSON? It turns out that if I omitted the toString() on server side, the date which is received is not correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Calendar dates

If, your date should represent a calendar date (e.g. New Year's is on Jan 1st, 00:00:00, independent of the time zone), then it's a good idea to send the date as a formatted String. So on the server side, you would do:

```java
// ISO 8601 format without (!) timezone
DateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"); 
Date myDate = new Date(...); // to avoid time zone problems here, prefer
                             // storing calendar dates on the server as
                             // Strings, too (or use Joda Time Partials)
String dateForClient = DATE_FORMAT.format(myDate);
```

And on the client side you could theoretically use

```java
JsDate jsDate = JsDate.parse(dateOnClient); // not ideal
```

However, JavaScript date parsing is somewhat unreliable, see e.g. http://blog.dygraphs.com/2012/03/javascript-and-dates-what-mess.html

So it's better to let GWT help you:

```java
DateTimeFormat dtf = DateTimeFormat.getFormat(PredefinedFormat.ISO_8601);
Date date = dtf.parseStrict(dateOnClient);
JsDate jsDate = JsDate.create(date.getTime());
```

#### Physical dates

If, however, your date should represent a physical point in time (e.g. the plane departed on Aug 21st, 10:00:00 UTC), then you could either

a) do the same as above, but modify the DATE_FORMAT on the server side to contain the time zone: `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");`

b) but probably it's a lot simpler to send the milliseconds value via JSON. So on the server side, you would do

```java
Date myDate = new Date();
String dateForClient = "" + myDate.getTime();
```

(Note, how we still use a String to transport the value, because the number range of JavaScript is not sufficient to transport all possible `long` values.)

And on the client side you would do

```java
JsDate jsDate = JsDate.create(new Long(dateOnClient));
```

#### More background

Unfortunately, Joda Time still cannot be used very well on the GWT client side, otherwise I would recommend reading about the distinction between physical dates ("Instants") and calendar dates ("Partials"), in the documentatation of Joda Time: http://www.joda.org/joda-time/key_instant.html

Comment: variant b: On server side, do I have the make a String out String dateForClient = (String)myDate.getTime() before doing encodeAsJSON() to get the transport correct?

Comment: That depends on which JSON library you use on the server side. But probably the library would try to convert the Long value into a JavaScript Number - and as I said above, the number range in JavaScript may not be big enough, so you get a number overflow - and if the number wraps around, you'll get unpredictable results. (Note: This is why GWT internally treats Long very specially, see http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsCompatibility.html#language). So to be safe, better transport it as a String.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the date in milliseconds to instantiate a JsDate. Both JsDate and java.util.Date are instantiable using a constructor that takes milliseconds.

```
JsDate jsDate = new JsDate(myDate.getTime());
```

Comment: But I have a String Date representation on the client side. Is there a way to convert a Java/Groovy Date into milliseconds?

Comment: You can parte the `java.util.Date` from the `String`, using `SimpleDateFormat` or `JodaTime`. Or it might be better to send the date information in milliseconds. `dateForClient = myDate.getTime();`

Comment: isn't that JsDate.create(myDate.getTime()); ?

Comment: Given your above, code, you'll have to do `JsDate.create(String.valueOf(jsonMessage.get("dateForClient").isString().stringValue()));`